# Magento database error "SQLSTATE[42S02]" after updating module

Tags: database, magento

I just updated the Magento module for confirming invoices with our government tax system, and now when I try to open "Fiskalni računi"

[image: Picture#1]

I get the following error:

[image: Picture#2]

and this is the error report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:281:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tb_topbiro.sales_flat_invoice' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tb_degriz_davcnablagajna_invoice` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_invoice` ON sales_flat_invoice.entity_id = main_table.parent_entity_id";i:1;s:6047:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(65883): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(55072): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(56109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(57047): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(55420): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(32084): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(31268): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(31254): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(32381): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(32428): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(550): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Degriz_DavcnaBlagajna_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Grid.php(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/BL_CustomGrid_Model_Grid_Rewriter_Eval.php(32) : eval()'d code(91): Degriz_DavcnaBlagajna_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(643): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Degriz_Davcnablagajna_Block_Adminhtml_Edit_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.php(649): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2616): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2335): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2279): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(13913): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2335): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2279): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#32 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3428): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3459): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#34 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(3473): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(2617): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#37 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(28827): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#38 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(14306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Degriz/DavcnaBlagajna/controllers/Adminhtml/Degriz/DavcnablagajnaController.php(21): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#40 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(14334): Degriz_DavcnaBlagajna_Adminhtml_Degriz_DavcnaBlagajnaController->indexAction()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(18826): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#42 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(18356): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#43 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/includes/src/__default.php(21292): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#44 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#45 /var/www/vhosts/topbiro.com/httpdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#46 {main}";s:3:"url";s:91:"/index.php/administration/degriz_davcnablagajna/index/key/fd6f0ff96daad9e222659251b664040f/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Please someone help me!

Comment: What's your Magento version ?

Comment: cache flushed ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: cache flushed, magento verzion 1.9.3.3...

Answer (score 0):

> *The table `sales_flat_invoice` doesn't exist. You can enable the flat catalog from admin panel.*

---

### EDIT

According to [Marius answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12006/24845):

> The `sales_flat_*` tables do not follow the same rules as the `catalog_flat_*` tables.

---